# Relational vs NoSql: Which database should I use for this kind of app?

Tags: ruby, database, nosql, relational-database, database-agnostic

I am about to build an application which does analytics on student results. Ghe data that needs to be stored looks like this:

```
Course: name
Semester: 1st,2nd etc
Student: name
Subject1: marks
Subject2: marks
Subject3: marks
Subject4: marks
Subject5: marks
Subject6: marks

GRAND TOTAL: marks
```

Subjects would vary according to the semester & course.  Ghe main requirements are:

1. Database should allow creation of various reports like exam-wise report, student-wise report, consolidated report, subject report etc.
2. It should have library for ruby as that's the language I have decided on.

So, should I choose relational or NoSQL database for this kind of application. If NoSQL, then which one?

**Question**
what is the best suited database for this use-case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering only the requirements you mentioned, I'd go with the simplest approach and use a RDBMS. 
I can't see any advantage in using NoSQL here because:

1. The data is well structured
2. It doesn't sound like a distributed system
3. NoSQL is not a magic solution for reporting. In fact it's not a solution for reporting :)
4. Considering your domain, performance should not be an issue
5. Considering your domain, you **do** care about ACID

However RDBMS has everything to get up and running:

1. Transactions
2. Low learning curve
3. Easy to implement basic reporting

So if the purpose is to get things done fast - I'd do it with RDBMS. If it's just for playing with databases - try implementing it with both technologies and then compare :)